# Port number change in sql server? Effect the application?

Tags: sql-server

When we change the port number of SQL server, is any changes we have to done in the web application, to connect the database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. There is a service that gets installed along with the database engine called SQL Browser that serves as a means to translate the instance name to a port. So, assuming that you didn't hard code the port number into the connection string, you should be good to go. Of course, you should test it first to make sure.